# Scanning string for valid Integer, problem with '+' sign

Tags: haskell

Have this small snippet for assigment task, and have to throw error if string isn't valid, as a part of assigment.

```
scanStringCC :: String -> Integer
scanStringCC x =
  if all (`elem` "+0123456789") x
    then read x :: Integer
    else error "Incorrect country code"
```

Normal strings work fine, ie `scanStringCC "1"` gives 1

`scanStringCC "a"` gives *** Exception: Incorrect country code, which is correct.

problem arises when i give `scanStringCC "+1"`, which throws Prelude.read: no parse

it should return 1, as 1::Integer.

why does it do that, and how to fix my snippet?

Comment: Because Haskell does not read an `Integer` that starts with a `+`. That looks like a function that will *add* `x` to a given value.

Comment: Hint: you can do pattern matching on the first character, if that is a `+`, then you parse the tail of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Willem, here is my solution

```
scanStringCC :: String -> Integer
scanStringCC x =
  if all (`elem` "+0123456789") x
    then (read (removePlus x)) :: Integer
    else error "Incorrect country code"
removePlus :: String->String
removePlus numString 
  | head (numString)=='+'=tail(numString)
  |otherwise=numString
```

I know its not super elegant, but have restrictions from automatic assigment, so good enough.

Comment: `removePlus ('+':rest) = rest; removePlus x = x` would be cleaner and safely handle empty strings. (Although `read` itself is going to fail on an empty string, you may as well push all the errors into one place.)

Comment: You can make it even more safe by also using `removePlus` in the check: ``all (`elem` "0123456789") (removePlus x)`` then I think you can be sure that `read` will only throw an error for the empty string. (Maybe do a let-binding first `let x' = removePlus x in if ...`)

Comment: am checking for empty string elsewhere.. whole program is bigger, and was built .. how could i say it.. modulary and chaotically